# No route matches for profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-profile

I am currently working on writing code to build a profile page for each user that signs into my application. However I have spent many hours and can't seem to figure this one out. Please excuse me for any lack of knowledge, I am rails beginner and still am learning.

I would like the application to be able to view and edit their own profile. Right now when signing into the application it is providing "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]"

_navigation_links.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to('Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %></li>      
  <li><%= link_to "View Profile", profile_path(@profile) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_profile_path(@profile) %></li> 
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

profiles_controller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :find_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
   before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
  @profiles = Profile.all
end

def show
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @profile = current_user.profile.build
end

def edit
end

def create
  @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

  @profile.save
  redirect_to @profile
end

def update
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
 if @profile.update(profile_params)
    redirect_to @profile
  else
    render 'edit'
  end 
end   

private

def find_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:id, :name, :summary, :birthday, :user_id)
end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :visitors, only: [:new, :create]
  root to: 'visitors#new'

  resources :posts
  resources :profiles


end
```

From what I am understanding the application can not find an ID for the profile page when a user is signed into the application. I am guessing that the ID needs to be created simultaneously as the user is signing up. However I am not sure how to implement this type of logic.

Comment: since you're using devise, you can just pass in `current_user`

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to rails, but my guess is that your @profile.save is unsuccessful and that @profile doesn't have an id. If it fails to save the profile to the database save will return false. So, add something like:

```
if @profile.save
  redirect_to @profile
else
  redirect_to 'new'
end
```

like you do for updates.
Could you perhaps have missed running the db migration after generating the profile model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup `@profile` on every page request when the `user_signed_in?`, as the `profile_path` route helper in the `_navigation_links.html.erb` depends on it.

So if the `user_is_signed_in?`, but is on the profiles_page which executes `ProfilesController#index` action, then it will fail, as you are setting `@profile` only for `[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`.